# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. The system cannot the specified file. Review Stack Trace

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller

After running the program in browser, the source error message says that there is a problem in ***ViewBag.userdetails = db.FirstTables.ToList();***

I get the following error message:

> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>   Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 15:         public ActionResult Index()
> Line 16:         {
> Line 17:             ViewBag.userdetails = db.FirstTables.ToList();
> Line 18:             return View();
> Line 19:         }
> ```

```
    ***Code:
    Controller:*** 

        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;
        using System.Data.Entity;

        namespace MovingApplication.Controllers
        {
            public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                MoveDBEntities db = new MoveDBEntities();

                [HttpGet]
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    ViewBag.userdetails = db.FirstTables.ToList();
                    return View();
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Index(string Prefix)
                {

                    var tempstring = (from N in db.FirstTables
                                      where N.name.StartsWith(Prefix)
                                      select new { N.name }).ToList();

                    List<Autocomplete> obj = new List<Autocomplete>();
                    foreach (var item in tempstring)
                    {
                        obj.Add(new Autocomplete() { name = item.name });
                    }
                    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }


                public ActionResult MoveData(string a)
                {
                    SecondTable t2 = new SecondTable();
                    t2.name = a;
                    db.SecondTables.Add(t2);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ViewBag.userdetails2 = db.SecondTables.ToList();
                    List<SecondTable> fundList = db.SecondTables.ToList();
                    ViewBag.userdetails3 = fundList;
                    return PartialView("_PartialViewX",t2);
                  //return Json(data2,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }

                public class Autocomplete
                {
                    public string name { get; set; }
                }
            }
}


    ***Model:***
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

        namespace MovingApplication.Models
        {
            public class Class1
            {
                public int id { get; set; }
                public string name { get; set; }
             }        
        }
```

Comment: I am guessing ViewBag code is not source of error. What happens if you comment that line? Also could you please add stack trace?

Comment: Is your connection string correct?

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty new to this. Where can I find the stack trace?

Comment: @PankajKapare. I did what you said and the app worked, but that makes my application completely useless. It just loads a basic webpage unfortunately.

Comment: Pankaj Kapare is just trying to confirm that the problem is with the database call and not elsewhere in the application.  To get the stack trace you can open the Output window (Ctrl+W, O) and copy/paste the last several lines.  Are you using nuget in this project?  If so, make sure all the packages are updated to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys! I was able to solve the issue by converting the data in the table to a list and then calling the list in the View. Seems to work fine till now.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.     Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.`

Please check your connection string it might be invalid. This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464.aspx) might help you. If sql server is out of memory freeing up memory may also work.